# Returning the last row of same id group in MySQL

Tags: mysql

thank you for giving answer but  not exact i am using same create payment receipt will not pay due amount i will less some amount like below example   your result                                                                cust_id   cust_name  invoice_id  paid_amount  due amount  makeapayment

1001       SAS              545      76           305          sasi                                           this your result ok but existing id   i have pay due amount 100 then create another row after view new row old row like above example row not view only stay in database   see  result like this                                                                                  cust_id   cust_name  invoice_id  paid_amount  due amount  makeapayment

1001       SAS              545       76           205          sasi

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT  pid,  cust_id, cust_name, date,  invoice_id, invoice_date, invoice_amount, paid_amount, paymentmade, makeapayment, due_amount, status FROM print_reciept  where due_amount!='0' ORDER BY cust_id DESC;
```